# How to get the name of the drive that the OS is installed on?

Tags: c#, .net

In C#, how do I get the name of the drive that the Operating System is installed on?

Comment: Do you mean like, "C:\" etc? Or do you mean the volume name like "Storage"?

Answer (score 35):

This should do it for you:

```
Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory)
```

Comment: Yep, about as simple as it gets!

Comment: Environment.SystemDirectory.Substring(0,3);

Answer (score 2):

All other Environment properties can be found at ms itself :    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment_properties.aspx

SystemDirectory  - Gets the fully qualified path of the system directory.

Answer (score 1):

There is an enum "SpecialFolder" in Environment where we can select the folder we are looking for..

Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

Comment: while your answer is in the right direction, i suggest you don't use the special folder "Desktop" in your example - use the SystemDirectory instead, since the desktop can be relocated to a network folder or another drive. I'll swap an edit on your part for an upvote on my part ;)