# How to get current windows directory e.g. C:\ in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

As the title suggests, how can you get the current OS drive, so you could add it in a string e.g.:

```
MessageBox.Show(C:\ + "My Documents");
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the name of the drive that the OS is installed on?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200066/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-drive-that-the-os-is-installed-on)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Add a reference to System.IO:

```
using System.IO;
```

Then in your code, write:

```
string path = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory);
```

Let's try it out by showing a message box.

```
MessageBox.Show($"Windows is installed to Drive {path}");
```

[image: Message box:]

Answer (score 15):

When looking for a specific folder (such as My Documents), **do not use a hard-coded path.**  Paths can change from version-to-version of Windows (`C:\Documents and Settings\` vs `C:\Users\`) and were localized in older versions (`C:\Users\user\Documents\` vs `C:\Usuarios\user\Documentos\`).  Depending on configuration, user profiles could be on a different drive than Windows.  Windows might not be installed where you expect it (it doesn't have to be in `\Windows\`).  There's probably other cases I'm not aware of.

Instead, use the Shell API (`SHGetKnownFolderPath`) to get the actual path.  In .NET, these values are easily obtained from [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath).  If you're looking for the user's My Documents folder:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

[Full list of special folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Environment.CurrentDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.currentdirectory) to get the current directory.  [Environment.SystemDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.systemdirectory) will give you the system folder (ie: C:\Windows\System32). [Path.GetPathRoot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getpathroot) will give you the root of the path:

```
var rootOfCurrentPath = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
var driveWhereWindowsIsInstalled = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a little parsing: [Environment.SystemDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.systemdirectory) returns the current directory.