# How to programmatically determine the PATH for a command?

Tags: windows, api

I am aware of Window's equivalent "whereis" command from this article:
https://superuser.com/questions/21067/windows-equivalent-of-whereis

But how does one perform the same using code? Is there a Windows API?

Comment: In which programming language?

Comment: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/SearchPath.html

Answer (score 2):

This example code in C#, using Linq, shows how to scan the PATH environment variable:

```
   static string SearchEnvPathForProgram(string filename)
    {
        return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH").Split(';')
               .Select(dir => Path.Combine(dir, filename))
               .FirstOrDefault(path => File.Exists(path));
    }
```

However, in case this is not sufficient for you and you need to mimic the complete behaviour of the `CreateProcess` function of the windows kernel, you have to extend this function by adding the other places listed in the comment of @HarryJohnston (thanks for the remark).

For example, the [folder of your current executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658518/getting-the-absolute-path-of-the-executable-using-c), the [current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653921/get-current-folder-path), or the [windows system directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249715/how-to-get-current-windows-directory-e-g-c-in-c-sharp). I guess you will find for each one a corresponding question here on SO.

Comment: The algorithm Windows uses is more complicated; for example, the application directory is checked first, followed by the current directory.  The path is at the bottom of the list, in sixth place.  Full details in the [documentation for CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

`LoadLibraryEx` followed by `GetModuleFileName` is one option, although it will only work if the file name you're searching for includes the `.exe` extension.

If safe DLL search mode is enabled (which it is by default on modern versions of Windows) you need to call `SetDllDirectory` first, passing the current directory as the argument.  Don't forget to call `SetDllDirectory(NULL)` afterwards to restore the default behaviour.

This may not be safe in a multithreaded program, because another thread might load a DLL while safe search mode is disabled.

Comment: Is it possible to call `CreateProcess` with `CREATE_SUSPENDED` and determine the path to the executable from the process handle?

Comment: Um ... maybe.  You can get the path from a process handle using `GetModuleFileNameEx` but I'm not entirely certain whether that will work with a process that hasn't started running yet.