# C# Directory of windows

Tags: windows

How to find the partition in which windows is installed using java or c#? so that the file access will be dynamic in different computers ie it will access the C: of D: where windows is installed

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the name of the drive that the OS is installed on?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200066/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-drive-that-the-os-is-installed-on)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this in c#. This will help you to get Windows directory.

```
String Text= Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir");
```

Comment: +1 anyway I would prefer to use Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows) to avoid any hard-coded string (even if it's almost impossible that it'll change!)

Comment: There is also the problem that you don't have environment variables in some scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

This should be `Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory)` in C#.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the property `SystemDirectory` of the `System.Environment` class in C#.

Answer (score 1):

For C# that would be `Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory)`, this will give you the root path like "C:\"