# C# program to know in which drive the windows Os is installed?

Tags: c#, windows

I wish to write a program in c# that determines in which directory the OS is installed.?

I mean  in some systems it is in "C" drive and in some systems it is in "D"  drive. I wish to know is there any way in C# programming language to know in which hard disk drive the OS is installed.

Regards,
Sai sindhu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the name of the drive that the OS is installed on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200066/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-drive-that-the-os-is-installed-on)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WINDIR")
```

UPDATE: you can also use `SpecialFolder.Windows` but as you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494.aspx) it also returns value corresponding to the %windir% or %SYSTEMROOT% environment variables.

Comment: This is more obscure *and* more easily forgeable than using Environment.SystemDirectory, IMO.

Comment: Maybe. But %WinDir% is very common to use. And it holds path where Windows installed. SystemDirectory on the other hand holds path to System32 folder, which is slightly different. Also I'd go with method like `GetWindowsDriveName` which will hide all this stuff.

Comment: There are any number of things which are "very common" but broken. Both the SystemDirectory and SpecialFolder.Windows  are better options, IMO.

Comment: Then I should rewrite all batch files, build events and other places where %windir% is used :)

Comment: It depends on the context. If you know that you're the only one to run those, and that you won't mess with WINDIR, it's fine. On the other hand, we *don't* know the OP's context. Maybe they're going to try to use this as part of some licence validation. To recommend using an environment variable with no caveats feels like a bad idea to me.

Answer (score 3):

```
   Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory)
```

Answer (score 2):

Or try this

```
Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
string windir = Path.GetPathRoot(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WINDIR"));
```

will return C:\ where windows is in C Drive

Answer (score 1):

`Environment.SystemDirectory` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8te35sa.aspx))