# How to check if Windows is installed on SSD or HDD?

Tags: c#

I am working on an app for improving performance in Windows. And there is a tip to use ReadyBoost. But ReadyBoost doesn't work on SSD. So, how do I check that if a Windows is on SSD or HDD?

Comment: Get the drive eg. with evaluating `%windir%` and then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726522/what-is-the-easiest-way-in-c-sharp-to-check-if-hard-disk-is-ssd-without-writing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the easiest way in C# to check if hard disk is SSD without writing any file on hard disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726522/what-is-the-easiest-way-in-c-sharp-to-check-if-hard-disk-is-ssd-without-writing)  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345825/c-sharp-program-to-know-in-which-drive-the-windows-os-is-installed