# Fnd the partitions information in the disk 0 using C#

Tags: c#

Is there any way to find the partitions information in the disk 0 using C#

What I want to do is getting the system partition (where the OS is located) in the disk 0.

I want the partition number where the OS is located.

Actually I need the Diskpart information of the partitions in disk 0.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200066/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-drive-that-the-os-is-installed-on

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory)
```

You can get other [Environment Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment_properties.aspx) From MSDN.